# Storing nodes in array

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Is it possible to store all content nodes as an array and pass to another template? I Have tried but cannot get it tho work. My select expression is selecting the correct nodes.

```
  <xsl:variable name="array" select="/data/contents/content[ .....  ] />
   <xsl:value-of select="$array/.../... " />


    <xsl:variable name="bannerList" select="data/contents[$dayOfWeekIndex]/content[position() &lt;= 5]" />

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$bannerList" mode="article">
        <xsl:with-param name="numberOfBanners" select="count($bannerList)" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

I would like to use call-template instead and send the bannerList as a parameter.

Comment: And might you be so kind as to provide us with an example of what you have so far?

Comment: Yes, you can pass a nodeset as a parameter, just like any other variable: `<xsl:with-param name="list" select="$bannerList" />`. Where is your XSLT where that isn't working as you expect?

Comment: I got the count($bannerList) = 1 as I expected. But when i try to access anything inside another template select="$bannerList/.../@somthing" I get an empty result.

Comment: Is `@somthing` an attribute of `content` elements? If so, it should be `$bannerList/@somthing`, not `$bannerList/../@somthing`. As I've already pointed out twice, you're failing to provide the necessary information (this time the source XML) to answer your question without continually asking you for information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is easily approachable, have a look:

**XML:**

```
<body>
  <RIAssetType><text>Product</text></RIAssetType>
  <RIAssetType><text>Service</text></RIAssetType>
  <RIAssetType><text>Company/Business Unit</text></RIAssetType>
  <RIAssetType><text>Technology</text></RIAssetType>
  <RIAssetType><text>Intellectual Property/Data Only</text></RIAssetType>
</body>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <copyBody>
    <xsl:call-template name="childCopy">
      <xsl:with-param name="bodyChild" select="self::body/child::*"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </copyBody>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="childCopy">
    <xsl:param name="bodyChild"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$bodyChild/self::*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<copyBody>
  <RIAssetType>
    <RIAssetType>
      <text>Product</text>
    </RIAssetType>
  </RIAssetType>
  <RIAssetType>
    <RIAssetType>
      <text>Service</text>
    </RIAssetType>
  </RIAssetType>
  <RIAssetType>
    <RIAssetType>
      <text>Company/Business Unit</text>
    </RIAssetType>
  </RIAssetType>
  <RIAssetType>
    <RIAssetType>
      <text>Technology</text>
    </RIAssetType>
  </RIAssetType>
  <RIAssetType>
    <RIAssetType>
      <text>Intellectual Property/Data Only</text>
    </RIAssetType>
  </RIAssetType>
</copyBody>
```

It seems you got struct in XPATH somewhere, please check again.